# Java arraylists search and replace elements in each list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have lists in an arraylist, elements are recurrent in lists. I would like to search for a specified element and replace the second element after it in all the lists.

```
for (int lj = 0; lj < arraynum; lj++) {
    for (int lk = 0; lk < adjLists.get(lj).size(); lk+=3) {
        if (adjLists.get(lj).get(lk) == adjLists.get(l).get(h)
            && adjLists.get(lj).get(lk + 1) == adjLists.get(l).get(h + 1)) {
            adjLists.get(lj).set(lk + 2, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Example - I search for 154 and 358, so zeros should be changed to 1:

> [288, 362, 0, 365, 85, 0, 137, 10, 0, 154, 358, 1]
>
> [285, 226, 0, 137, 10, 0, 20, 30, 1, 387, 297, 0, 154, 358, 1]

This code do it only for one match, not for all matches.

Comment: Are those two lists supposed to be the before and after?  I can't really tell what you're trying to do.  You say replace the one 2 after the match with 1, then say replace 0 with 1, but 0 isn't 2 after the matches...

Comment: Is your sample arraynum=2?

Comment: The question itself is so confusing .. you need to clear what you intended to do

Comment: adjLists.get(l).get(h) , here what is l and h ? Where have you defined it ?

Comment: @Thomas: lk position: 154, lk+1 : 358, lk+2: 0 Am I right?

Comment: @likeToCode: These are from another loop, contains the value to search for.

Comment: Then you need to post us all the relevant code, this is confusing.

Comment: @likeToCode: I have tested and it contains the needed value. It would be too much code...

Answer (score -1):

Look at this working example. In the for-each loop I iterate over each of the arrayLists and get an instance of them. Then I replace 0 with 1 while there are 0 in the list.

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Arrays.asList(288, 362, 0, 365, 85, 0, 137, 10, 0, 154, 358, 1));
list.add(Arrays.asList(285, 226, 0, 137, 10, 0, 20, 30, 1, 387, 297, 0, 154, 358, 1));

// This is where the real stuff happens
for(List<Integer> arrayList:list)
{
    while(arrayList.contains(0))
    {
        arrayList.set(arrayList.indexOf(0), 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how that example may work with your wrong type casting. Remove the cast to `ArrayList` to the result of `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: Have you even looked into the Arrays.asList method once in your life? Let me paste a code snippet in here:
`@SafeVarargs
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
        return new ArrayList<>(a);
    }`

Comment: Yes, and it returns an inner class called `ArrayList`, which **is not** the same as `java.util.ArrayList`. Just try to execute your code and see how it explodes in your environment.

Comment: @Distjubo: But I have two values as a condition and would like to change a third.

Comment: It worked for me. Sorry about this not working for you. But the code he wanted to have is NOT THAT, its the iterations.

Comment: This answer leaves out the part of the question where it's only replacing a value if two other values are found.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I have also wrote this.

Comment: I think @mum007 can EASILY add that one part to it.

Comment: Maybe : while(arrayList.contains(adjLists.get(lj).get(lk)) && arrayList.contains(adjLists.get(lj).get(lk+1))) ?

Comment: What about indexOf value in this case?

Comment: What do you even want to do: Do you want to replace 0 with 1 or what
I dont really get it

Comment: Still won't work, at least not if I only import `java.util.List; java.util.Arraylist; java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: @Distjubo: Yes, it should be make a simple replace, if the two values are correct, third should be changed.

Comment: It is not a good solution for 2 values: while(arrayList.contains(adjLists.get(l).get(h) && adjLists.get(l).get(h+1))) Don't working!